# An alternative way to pass data (eg, array values) through handler without using ScriptProperties

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I built an app in which I use `ScriptProperties` to store data from a handler to its `but(e)` function. This was working nice, until other people started using the same spreadsheet at the same time. So often happens that one person is taking a time thinking about what item choose from a checkbox menu and another person uses the same function, changing the data stored at scriptProperties and affecting the use of the function by the first person.
What is the best way to fix it, using an alternative way to pass information through the handler?
Here one sample of one of theese functions (in which I'm using `ScriptProperties` to pass the values of`letterSpreadsheetId` and `recipientArray`):

```
function letter(letterSpreadsheetId){
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('letterSpreadsheetId', letterSpreadsheetId); // different people may have different letterSpreadsheetId;
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('letter', 1); // to be used in another function
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(400).setWidth(600);
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel(); // you can embed that in a form panel
  var label = app.createLabel("Choose a receiver").setStyleAttribute("fontSize", 18);
  app.add(label);  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(letterSpreadsheetId).getSheetByName("receivers");
  var recipientArray = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();  
  var item3Panel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  item3Panel.add(app.createLabel("receiver"));
  var listBox = app.createListBox().setName('item3');  
      for(var i = 0; i < (recipientArray.length); i++){
           listBox.addItem(recipientArray[i][1]);
    }
  item3Panel.add(listBox);
  var recipientArrayStr = JSON.stringify(recipientArray);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('recipientArr', recipientArrayStr);
  var handlerBut = app.createServerHandler("butAnswerLetter").addCallbackElement(panel);
  var but = app.createButton("submit").setId("submitButton2").addClickHandler(handlerBut);
  panel.add(item1Panel)
       .add(item2Panel)
       .add(item3Panel)
       .add(but)
       .add(app.createLabel().setId("answer"));  
  var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(600, 400).setTitle("My title 1");
  scroll.add(panel);
  app.add(scroll);
  ss.show(app);
}

function butAnswerLetter(e){
  var letterSpreadsheetId = ScriptProperties.getProperty('letterSpreadsheetId');
  var recipient = e.parameter.item3;
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('recipient', recipient);
  var recipientArrayRecovery = ScriptProperties.getProperty('recipientArr');
  var recipientArray = JSON.parse(recipientArrayRecovery);
  for(var i=0;i<recipientArray.length;i++){
    if(recipient == recipientArray[i][1]){
        var usedRecipientArray = recipientArray[i];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities (that I know), either use userProperties instead of script-Properties as these are associated with the user but it will require the user to login and authorize, or - and this will work in every case even if the app is accessed anonymously, use the tags that you can write on almost any widget.

the syntax is quite simple, here is a small code example :

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test_TAG');
  var list = app.createListBox(true).setVisibleItemCount(5).setPixelSize(30,450).setName('list');
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('show').addCallbackElement(list);
  list.addChangeHandler(handler);
  var data = [];
  for(var n = 0;n<20;n++){
    list.addItem(n+' ');
    data.push('available value = '+Number(n+1));
  }
  list.setTag(data.toString());
  app.add(list);
  return app
}

function show(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var data = e.parameter.list_tag.split()
  var selected = e.parameter.list;
  app.add(app.createTextBox().setText(selected).setPixelSize(200,20));
  app.add(app.createTextArea().setText(data.join()).setPixelSize(200,300));
  return app;
}
```

[testable here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyAkyJdlcCQ1i6-VRbnwzELy5M9S68Sf4Xx1UwuiZU-351JnGQ/exec)

---

### Edit

following Zig's pertinent comment :

I forgot to mention the [hidden widget](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/hidden) (or a textBox / area set to invisible, useful for debugging when you want to check what it contains !  ) that is also useable of course...
The comment about a user having multiple windows showing the same app is also worth mentioning !

All in all you have 3 possibilities after all !

*(thanks to Zig Mandel)*

Comment: Or just store the needed data inside a 'hidden' in the ui. Properties are not at all for this. Even on a single user case it will break if the user has multiple windows open of the same app.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention it indeed - answer updated